# Log4j error: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator

Tags: spring, maven, log4j

I am trying to create a web project using spring framework. When trying to run the project, I am getting a HTTP Status 404 error in the browser.

Here is the stack trace of the problem from the console:

```
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1263\opl\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1263\opl\oplide\;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1263\cplex\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\IBM\ILOG\CPLEX_Studio_Community1263\cpoptimizer\bin\x64_win64;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60;C:\adb;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Zorba XQuery Processor 3.0.0\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60;C:\Program Files (x86)\SSH Communications Security\SSH Secure Shell;C:\Users\prati\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\prati\Downloads\eclipse-jee-mars-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:11 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CRUDWebAppMavenized' did not find a matching property.
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:11 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:11 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 656 ms
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:11 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Set web app root system property: 'webapp.root' = [C:\Users\prati\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp6\wtpwebapps\CRUDWebAppMavenized\]
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing log4j from [classpath:log4j.xml]
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/xml/DOMConfigurator
    at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:69)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.initLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:151)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextInitialized(Log4jConfigListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4939)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.xml.DOMConfigurator
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 12 more

Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/CRUDWebAppMavenized] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Shutting down log4j
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStop
SEVERE: Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/LogManager
    at org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer.shutdownLogging(Log4jConfigurer.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jWebConfigurer.shutdownLogging(Log4jWebConfigurer.java:169)
    at org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener.contextDestroyed(Log4jConfigListener.java:49)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4980)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5626)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.LogManager
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1702)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1547)
    ... 13 more

Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Apr 17, 2016 8:43:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 2193 ms
```

Here is my log4j.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//APACHE//DTD LOG4J 1.2//EN" "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <param name="Target" value="System.out" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p: %c - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="util" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:\\ITLab\\logs\\GeneralLogs.log" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
          <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%t %-5p %c{2} - %m%n"/>
        </layout>           
     </appender>

    <!-- Application Loggers -->
    <logger name="com.hp.gcc">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- 3rdparty Loggers -->
    <logger name="org.springframework.core">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.beans">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.context">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="org.springframework.web">
        <level value="info" />
    </logger>

    <!-- Root Logger -->
    <root>
        <priority value="warn" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Here is web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>CRUDWebAppMavenized</display-name>

  <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>CRUDWebAppMavenized</groupId>
  <artifactId>CRUDWebAppMavenized</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <properties>
    <org.springframework.version>3.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>        
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Hibernate resources -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.7.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.0.ga</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.184428</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>20030825.183949</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- MySQL -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Log4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


  <build>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/main/test</testSourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Kindly tell me what's wrong with my code, and please provide solutions. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: hi have u solve this issue? i hit this issue also and not sure how to solve it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i got it!

Problem is:
org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
This is deprecated from Spring Framework 4.2.1. Only delete this listener!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add the dependencies in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by using below pom dependency !

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.5-beta5</version>
</dependency>
```